# Wanna download source code of XLs compilers assuming they are in XLs not C++

Tags: compiler-construction

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XL_(programming_language)

[Looking for graph#tree transformer usage examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120499/looking-for-graphtree-transformer-usage-examples)

As here described I make new compiler of PL Ya http://Ya-Lang.com so in search for compiler construction tools: graph#tree transformers and output source code generators = pretty printers. XLs look like a good option. Yet after downloading **XL2 XLR** source code I see C++ not **XLs** ;(. But Wikipedia states

**WP XL PL>** a complete rewrite of the compiler was started in 2003. ..., and all new development is now written in **XL**.

How to download+explore the compiler source code?

Comment: What is "XL2 XLR"? What are you talking about?

Comment: @melpomene +
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XL_(programming_language)

Comment: That thing looks dead. Latest "News" is from January 2012. That said, there seems to be source code in e.g. https://sourceforge.net/p/xlr/git/ci/master/tree/xl2/native/.

Answer (score 0):

The initially downloaded sources, which I referred in the question as C++, they contain **3** **XL** compilers! of which the starting is in **C++**, the mid one is in **simplified XL** and the last one is in **full XL**!

Cool! Had to explore the file tree!